# Access Flask methods like before_request when using Connexion

Tags: python, flask, connexion

I'm building an API using Connexion, so I'm using `app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__)` instead of instead of `Flask(__name__)`.

I want to add `before_request` and `after_request` handlers to open and close a database connection. However, since `app` is a `connexion.FlaskApp` object, those decorator methods don't exist.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = models.db
    g.db.connection()


@app.after_request
def after_request():
    g.db.close()
```

How can I use `before_request` and other Flask methods when I'm using Connexion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Connexion instance stores the Flask instance as the [`app` attribute](https://github.com/zalando/connexion/blob/08faf2aa86fb62e75704c5aa90c6fea840c6b809/connexion/apps/abstract.py#L54). You can still use all the things available to Flask through that.

```
app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__)

@app.app.before_request
def open_db():
    ...
```

Connexion itself does this, for example their `route` method passes to [`self.app.route`](https://github.com/zalando/connexion/blob/08faf2aa86fb62e75704c5aa90c6fea840c6b809/connexion/apps/abstract.py#L235).